# Yum adds the dir 'Package' to baseurl

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

I'm on a network that doesn't get outside internet. I have the repo file pointing to a http server on the network that has the packages that came with the RHEL install cd. Most of the servers work correctly, but one of them wants to add the directory 'Packages' to the end of the line.

```
[RHEL63]
name= RHEL 6.3 Repository
baseurl=http://myserver/rpm/RHEL6-3
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

When I try to install, it finds the dependencies (so apparently it sees them) and asks me if I want to continue. Then I get a bunch of error messages because it's looking for the rpms in the directory 'Packages'.

```
Downloading Packages:
http://myserver/rpm/RHEL6-3/Packages/389-ds-base-1.2.10.2-15.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
```

I've done a `yum clean all` and similar urls for other RHEL versions work with other servers.

**EDIT**

I've created a 'Packages' directory and have copied all of the rpms to that location which solved the issue. My main concern is why it has that behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your yum client configuration probably indicates to access a URL, and that directory includes a file named ".treeinfo".  If you have a look at the this file you'll see it specifies a directive called `packagedir` which probably is set to "Packages".

The usual pattern is the copy the entirety of the contents of the RHEL ISO into a local location, which will include the Packages directory (which houses the packages), along with all of the repo data required for it to work with yum.